# Extracting public data from Facebook in a legal way

Tags: facebook, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I want to make an application that needs to collect some public data from facebook.
Specifically I need to check reactions and comments made on public posts.

I've noticed two things:
First, According to https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php, 
scraping is not allowed unless facebook gives you a written permission. (of which how do I ask for permission anyway?)
Second, as far as I see the graph api doesn't allow to get information regarding posts made by another user/page. Am I wrong?

How do I get the information I need in a legal way and is it even possible?

Comment: you can get information about other pages, you just have to go through a review process, that´s all.

Answer (score 1):

To get public posts in a page and reactions and comments on these posts your app will need will need **Page Public Content Access** permission. If you have not already created the app, you can find how to do this in this link and how to review your app for permissions in this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/).

Once you have the permission you can **get public posts from a page** using below API request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<PAGE_ID>/posts?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&fields=name
```

Get the **id of posts** you need details for from the response of the above request

Then you can use the below request's to get reactions and comments of the post based on the post id

**Get total reactions:**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<POST_ID>?fields=reactions.summary(true)&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

**Get total reactions of a specific type** (NONE, LIKE, LOVE, WOW, HAHA, SAD, ANGRY, THANKFUL, PRIDE):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<POST_ID>?fields=reactions.summary(true).type(<REACTION_TYPE>)&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

**Get comments:**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<POST_ID>?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&fields=comments.summary(true).limit(999).filter(stream).fields(id,message,created_time,parent)
```

And as for public posts by a user you will be able to get the total reactions with the same request by providing the post id if the post is public, but you cannot get the comments, however you will get the comments count